Taking publishing fee from co authors people who are involve in writing
Aoa, i do medical researches and get articles published in journal ,if i take money from my co authors(other people participating in writing) for publication purpose which actually is not costing me anything is it wrong ?

If you say that this is a contribution to the fee you pay, it's a lie.
It's also a lie if the co-authors pay for being mentioned as such although they have not contributed.
Lying is certainly haram.
If you said clearly that it is you who is charging them before they worked, and they consented, the treaty would be valid. That doesn't mean that it is fair
